# Excel Macro to cycle through all rows

Tags: vba, excel

I receive data in Excel rows like so:

```
INVOICE NO. 1000001
Plan AAAAA 17371 22.00
Plan BBBBB 31782 0.00
Plan CCCCC 13918 44.00
Total for 1000001 66.00
INVOICE NO. 1000002
Plan AAAAA 31385 0.00
Plan CCCCC 15981 44.00
Total for 1000002 44.00
INVOICE NO. 1000003
Plan BBBBB 13181 0.00
Plan CCCCC 01828 16.00
GARBAGE TEXT
Total for 1000003 16.00
```

I need to make this data display on a separate sheet (or even replace the current sheet) like so:

```
Invoice No | Plan AAAAA | Plan AAAAA Cost | Plan BBBBB | Plan BBBBB Cost | Plan CCCCC | Plan CCCCC Cost | Total
1000001 | Plan AAAAA 17371 | 22.00 | Plan BBBBB 31782 | 0.00 | Plan CCCCC 13918 | 44.00 | 66.00
1000002 | Plan AAAAA 31385 | 0.00 | | | Plan CCCCC 15981 | 44.00 | 44.00
1000003 | | | Plan BBBBB 13181 | 0.00 | Plan CCCCC 01828 | 16.00 | 16.00
```

Some things to note are:

1. I can't change how I receive this data. I wish I could.
2. Each set of invoice starts with `INVOICE NO. XXXXXXX` and ends with `Total for XXXXXXX` followed by its total cost.
3. There are only 3 possible plans AAAAA/BBBBB/CCCCC but not all 3 may appear within an invoice.
4. Sometimes there is garbage text in the middle of the output which needs to be ignored.

I was thinking to create an Excel macro that would go through each line of an Excel sheet, pseudo-code being

1. Create new table with desired headings
2. Find first instance of `INVOICE NO` and add following number to table
3. Check next line, while line does not contain `Total for`, check if contains `Plan AAAAA`, if so add line to table while splitting last part as cost, if not leave black, stay on line and check for Plan BBBBB, repeat for BBBBB and CCCCC

How do I loop through every row doing the above (or is there any better way to accomplish this)?

Comment: Great explaination. what you did so far? can you please post that code

Comment: This is a simple Project to learn VBA, pointers: loop from row 1 to lastrow on column A (or loop until IsEmpty cell), use `If ... Then` blocks for **INVOICE NO. ** and **Total for **, then `Select Case` for the plans for designated columns.

Comment: Please format your data inserts properly. Maybe use a [markdown table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). As it is, it is impossible to be certain of how your data is distributed across columns in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is written in comments in code, I asumed your data is stored in column A starting with `A1` cell. Then, it will be replaced by desired output (you said that is allowed).

Try this code:

```
Sub ParseInvoices()
Dim lsatRow As Long, i As Long, invoiceData As Variant, currentRow As Long, currentData As String
currentRow = 2
'get last row of A column - I assumed that there you store your data
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'read data
invoiceData = Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Value
'clear data from sheet
Columns(1).Clear
'set up table headers
Cells(1, 1) = "Invoice No"
Cells(1, 2) = "Plan AAAAA"
Cells(1, 3) = "Plan AAAAA Cost"
Cells(1, 4) = "Plan BBBBB"
Cells(1, 5) = "Plan BBBBB Cost"
Cells(1, 6) = "Plan CCCCC"
Cells(1, 7) = "Plan CCCCC Cost"
Cells(1, 8) = "Total"

For i = 1 To lastrow
    currentData = RTrim(LTrim(invoiceData(i, 1)))
    Select Case UCase(Left(currentData, 10))
        Case "INVOICE NO"
            Cells(currentRow, 1).Value = Mid(currentData, InStrRev(currentData, " "))
        Case "PLAN AAAAA"
            Cells(currentRow, 2).Value = Left(currentData, InStrRev(currentData, " ") - 1)
            Cells(currentRow, 3).Value = Mid(currentData, InStrRev(currentData, " "))
        Case "PLAN BBBBB"
            Cells(currentRow, 4).Value = Left(currentData, InStrRev(currentData, " ") - 1)
            Cells(currentRow, 5).Value = Mid(currentData, InStrRev(currentData, " "))
        Case "PLAN CCCCC"
            Cells(currentRow, 6).Value = Left(currentData, InStrRev(currentData, " ") - 1)
            Cells(currentRow, 7).Value = Mid(currentData, InStrRev(currentData, " "))
        Case "TOTAL FOR "
            Cells(currentRow, 8).Value = Mid(currentData, InStrRev(currentData, " "))
            currentRow = currentRow + 1
    End Select
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Not so flexible code but it works based from the criteria above:

```
Sub test()


Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet

Sheets(2).Range("a1").Value = "Invoice No"
Sheets(2).Range("b1").Value = "Plan AAAAA"
Sheets(2).Range("c1").Value = "Plan AAAAA Cost"
Sheets(2).Range("d1").Value = "Plan BBBBB"
Sheets(2).Range("e1").Value = "Plan BBBBB Cost"
Sheets(2).Range("f1").Value = "Plan CCCCC"
Sheets(2).Range("g1").Value = "Plan CCCCC Cost"
Sheets(2).Range("h1").Value = "Total"

sheet2y = 1

For y = 1 To 10000
    If Len(Sheets(1).Cells(y, 1).Value) > 0 Then
            If LCase(Sheets(1).Cells(y, 1).Value) Like "*invoice*" Then
                If sheet2y > 1 Then
                    Sheets(2).Cells(sheet2y, 8).Value = Sheets(2).Cells(sheet2y, 3).Value + Sheets(2).Cells(sheet2y, 5).Value + Sheets(2).Cells(sheet2y, 7).Value
                End If
                sheet2y = sheet2y + 1
                Sheets(2).Cells(sheet2y, 1).Value = Trim(Split(LCase(Sheets(1).Cells(y, 1).Value), "no.")(1))

            End If


        If LCase(Sheets(1).Cells(y, 1).Value) Like "*plan*" Then
            For sheet2x = 2 To 6 Step 2
                If LCase(Sheets(1).Cells(y, 1).Value) Like "*" & LCase(Sheets(2).Cells(1, sheet2x).Value) & "*" Then
                    Sheets(2).Cells(sheet2y, sheet2x).Value = Sheets(2).Cells(1, sheet2x).Value & " " & Split(Sheets(1).Cells(y, 1).Value, " ")(2)
                    Sheets(2).Cells(sheet2y, sheet2x + 1).Value = Trim(Split(Sheets(1).Cells(y, 1).Value, " ")(3))
                End If
            Next sheet2x
        End If

    Else
        Sheets(2).Cells(sheet2y, 8).Value = Sheets(2).Cells(sheet2y, 3).Value + Sheets(2).Cells(sheet2y, 5).Value + Sheets(2).Cells(sheet2y, 7).Value
        Exit For
    End If
Next y

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of For-Each loops, here. It'd go s.th. like this:

```
For Each rw In sheet.Rows
    If rw.Cells(1, 1).Value = "<YOUR STRING HERE>" Then 
    ...
Next rw
```

If you do that as explained in your own pseudo code I see no reason it shouldn't work. However, this kind of looks like a question for upwork ;)